# How to make @current_user available in my views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application controller I have a module that I include like:

```
require 'current_user'
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include CurrentUser


end
```

So if there is a token cookie set, it looks up the user.

In my views i am doing this:

```
<% if @current_user.present? %>
...
..
```

This doesn't work currently in my views because there is no @current_user or current_user in my views.

How can I create a @current_user variable globally for all my view pages to access?

Comment: whats in that `CurrentUser` include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my module I just some ruby metaprogramming to include it in my `application_controller` class:

```
module CurrentUser
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :helper_method, :current_user
  end
end
```

Now `current_user` works in my views.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your module does, but you can just make a method on in `ApplicationController`:

```
def current_user
  # ... fetch current_user somehow...via your module method, or session:
  @current_user ||= session[:user_id] ? User.find(session[:user_id]) : nil
end
```

Then you can access it in your views via:

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
```

If you really want to force it to be `@current_user`, I guess the easiest way would be to add it as a `before_action`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :set_current_user

private

    def set_current_user  
        @current_user = session[:user_id] ? User.find(session[:user_id]) : nil
    end
end
```

Now you can access it in views via `@current_user`, but it will be eagerly fetched even if you aren't using it in your views. Using first method will only query for current user if you use it.